# PHP Delete all files except the following

Tags: php

I've got this script working to delete all files but leave just the selected ones, How can i change it so on the .exe file it catches any filename?

```
$leave_files = array(''.$filename.'.exe', ''.$filename.'.nfo', ''.$filename.'.sfv');
foreach( glob("$foldername/*") as $file ) {
    if( !in_array(basename($file), $leave_files) ) {
            unlink($file);
        }
```

for the .exe file i want it to capture ANY filename

Thanks

Comment: You want it to delete all files except what is listed in the array *and* not any .exe file?

Comment: No sorry, i want it to keep $filename.nfo, $filename.sfv and ANYNAME.exe

Comment: OK, that's what I answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$leave_files = array('' . $filename . '.exe', '' . $filename . '.nfo', '' . $filename . '.sfv');

foreach (glob("$foldername/*") as $file) {
    if (!in_array(basename($file), $leave_files)) {
        if (substr($file, -4) == ".exe") {
            continue;
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need the particular.exe anymore just re-read what i wrote didn't make perfect sense. I just want ANYTHING.exe to be kept and not deleted.

Comment: sorry its for anything.exe only. I forgot to remove "particular" from the script.

Comment: Should if (substr($file, -4) == ".exe") { be $filename? Its not working currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the last 4 signs of the filename are ".exe" and then don't delete them. (or delete them, depends on what you mean)

> if(substr($filename,-4) == ".exe")

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension:

```
if(!in_array(basename($file), $leave_files) && pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'exe') {
```

Or exclude them in the `glob()`:

```
foreach(array_diff(glob("$foldername/*"), glob("$foldername/*.exe") as $file) {
```

Comment: Where would this go inside my script?

Comment: They would replace your existing `if` OR your existing `foreach`.  Whichever makes the most sense to you.